# JavaScript code won't work On My Blogger Site

Tags: javascript, blogger, jsfiddle

I have made [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) code using the fiddle.com website. But in fiddle I can only make it work by using the

> no wrap (body)

option. I'm not sure what this option does. The link for the Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GDXuS/3/). I added this script to my [Blogger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blogger_%28service%29) blog, but it would not work.

#### Code

```
function getTotal(){
    var form = document.theForm;
    var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var length = inputs.length;
    var total = '0';

    for (i = 0; i<length-1; i++){
        if(inputs[i].type == 'radio'){
            var checked = inputs[i].checked?1:0;
            if(checked){
                var value = inputs[i].value.split("~~")[0];
                total -= -value;
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('totalspan').innerHTML="Toplam Fiyat: "+ total + " tl"
    total='0';
}
```

The script is to calculate a total price of the selections. You can see it in the fiddle. Also, I have it on Blogger, but as I said it's not working.

The link to my blog is [here](http://hackintoshturkey.blogspot.com/).

Comment: No offense but your copy-paste skills sucks. Checking for syntax errors in *any* JavaScript console should be enough

Comment: i have already in fiddle. It just wont work with blogger. It doesnt give any errors either.just not working.. Should i host a javascript file and make a link on the html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`no wrap (body)` means that your script will be inserted in new `script` tag inside `body` tag, `no wrap (head)` means that your script will be inserted in new `script` tag inside `head`. You can read about it on [jsFiddle help](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#choose-framework)

Other options will wrap your JS code inside particular DOM event handlers (`onLoad` and `onDomReady`)

Script errors on your site tells me that `calculateTotal is not defined`, so please check your naming.

Why do you use string when calculating total? You can safely use native JS `parseInt` funciton.

Another point that using form `click` event is wrong, you should use `change` event of your inputs.

Simplest option for you is to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) like this:

```
$('[name="CPU"], [name="OperatingSystem"], [name="Case"]').on('change', updateTotal);

function updateTotal {
   var total = 0;
   // calculate your total here
   $('#totalspan').text(total);
}
```

Please check my 5-min fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GDXuS/5/

You could also use `data-` attributes to store price or any other data (see on [jQuery site](http://api.jquery.com/data/)).

And I'm advice you to study some programming languages.

Comment: No problem, just accept my answer if it helps =)
Have a look at JS tutorial at [w3c.org](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)